# War Magic and Extra Attack? Can it work?

Tags: dnd-5e, fighter

I'm asking if when I use extra attack, can I attack then cast a spell then bonus attack?

Answer (score 6):

**No.**

War Magic allows you to use a bonus action to make a weapon attack after you've previously used an action to cast a cantrip. The Attack action is a separate action.

You could, however, use your action surge to do this. You would get two attacks (from the Attack action), then Action Surge and use your second action to cast a cantrip. This would then allow you to use your bonus action to attack a third time with a weapon.

Comment: To clarify, casting a cantrip is the "Cast a Spell" action, and making a weapon attack (up to two with Extra attack) is still your entire "Attack" action. You cannot sacrifice the Extra Attack feature to cast a cantrip, because those are two different actions.